# Do hashtags interfere with lookaheads in a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've tried to capture some data in between a lookbehind and a lookahead. My test string:

```
#2000 STEPS OF EQUILIBRATION AT LAMBDA 0 COMPLETED
#STARTING COLLECTION OF ENSEMBLE AVERAGE
TI 2000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -25.1615 -26.5570 23.3878 41.9173
TI 2050 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -27.0891 -27.0786 27.0495 27.3411
TI 2100 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -26.1894 -26.6384 14.5814 21.0244
TI 2150 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -24.3845 -25.8921 21.6334 21.2261
TI 2200 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -27.1072 -26.1944 27.0034 22.6632
TI 2250 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -22.1403 -25.3868 21.6304 22.4575
TI 2300 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -24.9672 -25.3171 18.2003 21.7503
TI 2350 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -23.7720 -25.0970 12.1601 20.3842
TI 2400 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -25.3668 -25.1306 21.8929 20.5723
#NEW TI WINDOW: LAMBDA 0.05
```

I've tried to get the TI rows as a block with the following regular expression:

```py
import re

pat = "(?<=STARTING COLLECTION OF ENSEMBLE AVERAGE\n)[\w\W]+(?=#NEW TI WINDOW)"

dats = re.findall(pat,string)
```

It works perfectly fine on [pythex](https://pythex.org/), but in spyder my pattern goes over the lookahead and captures everything. Even if I use \ # in my lookahead, it still captures everything. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall()` needs capturing groups as in

```
pat = "STARTING COLLECTION OF ENSEMBLE AVERAGE\n([\w\W]+?)#NEW TI WINDOW"
dats = re.findall(pat, string)
print(dats)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BoP7gI/1).